# What is the overhead of using Arc<str> vs Arc<Box<str>>

Tags: rust

In this [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1845-shared-from-slice.md#for-arc), it is mentioned that

> For Arc the synchronization overhead of doing `.clone()` is probably greater than the overhead of doing `Arc<Box<str>>`

What kind of synchronization overhead is meant here?
As far as I understand, cloning any Arc, no matter what the wrapped type is, will incur synchronization overhead. So what am I missing here, or do I simply misunderstand something about `doing Arc<Box<str>>` part in the above statement?

Comment: (Ignore my previous comment.) Is it cheaper to put smaller things in an `Arc`? The stack-allocated portion of a `Box` is small, so it might be cheaper to place a `Box<T>` in an `Arc` than the `T` itself if `T` is large. The locality they refer to later is probably that `*Box<T>` is a single deref whereas `*Arc<Box<T>>` is two.

Comment: @BallpointBen I'm not fully understand your intent, but if it's the meaning, then it applies to `Rc` too.